# vhd xlinix something is wrong same values it must be with muxes

Tags: vhdl, mips, mips32

I have a problem with my program in xilinx vhd.
I have to create a processor that supports the classic instructions of MIPS32
add, sub, and, or, lw, sw, sine and cosine. Sine and Cosine will take as argument a number and will return the cos or sin of the angle in ΙΕΕΕ-754 Single precision and Integer from 0 – 1000.
I have an excel file which produce a hex output(for the commands of Mips32) that i use in one components(in InstructionRom)
The input numbers that I want to add or sub or and ..etc..I write them in HEX in the component DataRam.

The problem is with the top component in ReadData1 and ReadData2 I got the same values.
Below I have 2 screenshots and how the top entity is connected with other components.
Other components are working.
Can anyone take a look please?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity myTOP is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
              instruction : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
              regA : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
              regB : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
              ALUout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
              writeReg : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
              Opcode : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0);
              SinCos : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
              DataOUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
              ReadDATA1 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           ReadDATA2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
              WriteData : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end myTOP;

architecture Behavioral of myTOP is

component InstructionsROM is
    Port ( InstructionAddress : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
           Instruction : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;

component myPCRegister is
    Port ( PC_INPUT : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
           PC_OUTPUT : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RESET : in  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component my_10bitAdder is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC;
           cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           z : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));
end component;


component my_5bitMUX is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           s : in  STD_LOGIC;
           z : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0));
end component;

component my32to9bit is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           z : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0));
end component;

component my32BitRegistersFile is
    Port ( ReadRegister1 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           ReadRegister2 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           WriteRegister : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           WriteData : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           ReadData1 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           ReadData2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
              ReadData3 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           RegWrite : in  STD_LOGIC;
              clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component myControlUnit is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0);
           RegDst : out  STD_LOGIC;
           ALUSrc : out  STD_LOGIC;
           MemtoReg : out  STD_LOGIC;
           RegWrite : out  STD_LOGIC;
           MemRead : out  STD_LOGIC;
           MemWrite : out  STD_LOGIC;
           ALUop1 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           SinCos : out  STD_LOGIC;
           FI : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component my16to32bit is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           z : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;


component myALUControl is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           s : in  STD_LOGIC;
           op1 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           op2 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           bin : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component myALU_32bit is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           bin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           op1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           op2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           z : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;

component my_SinCos is
    Port ( I1 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
           s : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
              e : out STD_LOGIC;
           O : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));

end component;

component DataRAM is
    Port ( DataAddress : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           readData : in  STD_LOGIC;
           writeData : in  STD_LOGIC;
           DataIn : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           DataOut : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;

component my_32bitMUX is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           s : in  STD_LOGIC;
           z : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;

signal S2, S4, S5, S6, S7, S9 , S10 , S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
signal S0, S1:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
signal S3:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
signal S8:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
signal SC:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);  
signal SA :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0); 
signal S18:STD_LOGIC;
begin
U0:  myPCRegister port map(PC_INPUT=>S1, PC_OUTPUT=>S0, clk=>clk, RESET=>reset);
U1:  my_10bitAdder port map (a=>S0, b=>'1', cin=>'0', z=>S1);
U2:  InstructionsROM port map(InstructionAddress=>S0 , Instruction=> S2 );
U3:  my_5bitMUX port map( a=> S2(15 downto 11), b=>S2(20 downto 16), s=>SC(0), z=>S3);
U4:  my32BitRegistersFile port map(ReadRegister1=>S2(25 downto 21), ReadRegister2=>S2(20 downto 16), WriteRegister=>S3, WriteData=>S17, ReadData1=>S5, ReadData2=>S6, RegWrite=>SC(3), clk=>clk, Reset=>reset );
U5:  myControlUnit port map(A=>S2(31 downto 26),RegDst=>SC(0), ALUSrc=>SC(1), MemtoReg=>SC(2), RegWrite=>SC(3), MemRead=>SC(4), MemWrite=>SC(5), ALUop1=>SC(6), SinCos=>SC(7), FI=>SC(8));
U6:  my16to32bit port map(a=>S2, z=>S4);
U7:  myALUControl port map(a=>S2(2 downto 0), s=>SC(6),bin=>SA(0), op1=>SA(1), op2=>SA(2));
U8:  my_32bitMUX port map(a=>S4, b=>S6, s=>SC(1), z=>S10);
U9:  my_32bitMUX port map(a=>S11, b=>S5, s=>SC(8), z=>S9);
U10: myALU_32bit port map(a=>S9, b=>S10, cin=>'0', bin=>SA(0), op1=>SA(1), op2=>SA(2), z=>S12);
U11: my_32bitMUX port map(a=> S5, b=>S12, s=>SC(8), z=>S7);
U12: my32to9bit port map(a=>S7, z=>S8);
U13: my_SinCos port map(I1=>S8, s=>S2(31 downto 30), e=>S18, O=>S11);
U14: DataRAM port map(DataAddress=>S2(9 downto 0), clk=>clk, readData=>SC(4), writeData=>SC(5), DataIn=>S6, DataOut=>S14);
U15: my_32bitMUX port map(a=>S12, b=>S11, s=>SC(8), z=>S13);
U16: my_32bitMUX port map(a=>S14, b=>S12, s=>SC(2), z=>S15);
U17: my_32bitMUX port map(a=>S11, b=>S15, s=>SC(7), z=>S16);
U18: my_32bitMUX port map(a=>S11, b=>S16, s=>S18, z=>S17);
instruction<=S2;
regA<=S9;
regB<=S10;
ALUout<=S12;        
writeReg<=S3;
Opcode<=S2(31 downto 26);
SinCos<=    S11;
DataOUT<=S14;
WriteData<=S17;
ReadDATA1<= S5;
ReadDATA2 <=S6;
end Behavioral;
```

DATARAM

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity DataRAM is
    Port ( DataAddress : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           readData : in  STD_LOGIC;
           writeData : in  STD_LOGIC;
           DataIn : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           DataOut : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end DataRAM;

architecture Behavioral of DataRAM is

-- Define a new type with the name RAM_Array of 8 bits
type RAM_Array is array (0 to 1023)
    of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
-- Set some initial values in RAM for Testing
signal RAMContent: RAM_Array := (
    0 => X"0A",   1 => X"00",   2 => X"00",  3 => X"00",
    4 => X"05",   5 => X"00",   6 => X"00",  7 => X"00",
    8 => X"2C",   9 => X"01", 10 => X"00", 11 => X"00", 
    12 => X"00", 13 => X"00", 14 => X"00", 15 => X"00",

    others => X"00");

begin   
    -- This process is called when we READ from RAM
    p1: process (readData, DataAddress)
    begin
        if readData = '1' then
         DataOut(7 downto 0) <= RAMContent(conv_integer(DataAddress));
         DataOut(15 downto 8) <= RAMContent(conv_integer(DataAddress+1));
         DataOut(23 downto 16) <= RAMContent(conv_integer(DataAddress+2));
         DataOut(31 downto 24) <= RAMContent(conv_integer(DataAddress+3));
        else
            DataOut <= (DataOut'range => 'Z');
        end if;
    end process;


    -- This process is called when we WRITE into RAM
    p2: process (clk, writeData)
    begin
        if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
            if writeData ='1' then
                RAMContent(conv_integer(DataAddress)) <= DataIn(7 downto 0);
                RAMContent(conv_integer(DataAddress+1)) <= DataIn(15 downto 8);
                RAMContent(conv_integer(DataAddress+2)) <= DataIn(23 downto 16);
                RAMContent(conv_integer(DataAddress+3)) <= DataIn(31 downto 24);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

INSTRUCTION ROM

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity InstructionsROM is
    Port ( InstructionAddress : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
           Instruction : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end InstructionsROM;

architecture Behavioral of InstructionsROM is
-- Define a new type with the name ROM_Array of 32 bits
type ROM_Array is array (0 to 1024)
    of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

-- The data here should be replaced with the intructions in HEX
constant ROMContent: ROM_Array := (
                    X"8C000000",

                    X"8C810000",
                    X"00201822",
                    X"00201824",
                    X"00201825",
                    X"8D000000",
                    X"8D810000",
                    X"BC03000A",
                    X"FC03000A",
                    X"3C03000A",
                    X"7C03000A",

    others =>   X"00000000");
begin

    Instruction <= ROMContent(conv_integer(InstructionAddress));

end Behavioral;
```

DataRam and instructionrom were given to us ready ..we just change the values (it depends on what instruction we want to do)

Comment: Sorry, but your code is very hard to read! Why don't you use clearly understandable signal names instead of `S<n>`? Why has your MIPS 3 readable Operands (and only 2 addresses)? Don't write long port maps in a single line. It's not clear so see which ports are in and out, especially by using meaningless names (Every component has an input a, but this are not the same wire). Why uses your DataRAM 8 bit values, whereas your MIPS is 32 bit? Why has your DataRAM no byte enable wires? MIPS has several load/store instructions for (s)byte, (u)short, (u)word.

Comment: This question appears to have had its code removed several times by the OP over the last couple of years - since the below answers are related to the question showing code, it should be kept in that state.

Comment: I captured the code January 1, 2015. The waveform on imgur that went with it is unavailable. This question is ripe for closing (now as unclear, previously for not being an MCVE, lacking a means of identifying the error, the correct value and reproducing the error). Tinkering with my answer to discourage a non-participating user (this is his only activity) from removing the source again is tilting at windmills @halfer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @user1155120.

Comment: (I am afraid I don't know enough about the topic above to determine if the question is unclear, but I welcome knowledgeable people voting that way if they wish).

Comment: I no longer have the OP's waveform or the testbench I wrote to go with the answer I gave. Without one of the two there's no way to identify the answer nor can a now non-participating OP accept an answer. Sprinkling up votes seems counter indicated.

Comment: @user1155120: I haven't made any upvotes on this page, sprinkled or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some serious problems with your code:

- `P1`: process sensitivity list should include `RAMContent`
- `U1`: `cout` is not connected
- `U4`: `readdata3` is not connected
- `U10`: `cout` is not connected
- `U14`: `component` `my_32bitMUX_937286` is not declared. This gives a compilation error

The first four problems can cause problems without warnings from your simulator. The last is an error and would normally cause your simulator to throw and error and refuse to start the simulation.